# проблема с деплоем на github Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

В общем сделал React  приложение, собрал с помощью gh-pages, проект залился, открываю, а там прогрузился только один компонент из проекта и лоадер, который вечно крутится, а в консоли бесконечные ошибки AxiosError. Если билд проекта запускаю локально всё работает. [ссылка на билд](https://github.com/catDonutInsane/Valantis/tree/gh-pages)

[ссылка на проект](https://catdonutinsane.github.io/Valantis/)

как буд-то скрипты не подтягиваются, я не понимаю

P.S. оказывается приложение запрашивает данные через http , а не через https, поэтому и не грузит, но теперь вопрос, как сделать чтобыгрузило?